# Indexing object with a generic key

Tags: typescript, generics

First time I've run into this issue so apologies if the title doesn't make sense, couldn't figure out a good way to word it.

I'm working with an API that returns a response like this:

```
{
  PaginatedResults: {
    TotalResults:  100,
    Offset: 0,
    Limit: 0,
    PageSize: 100,
  },
  Error: {
    Message: '',
    Code: '',
  },
  Customers: [{...}]
}
```

Where `Customers` can be replaced with any type the API may return. So it could also look something like this:

```
{
  PaginatedResults: {
    TotalResults:  100,
    Offset: 0,
    Limit: 0,
    PageSize: 100,
  },
  Error: {
    Message: '',
    Code: '',
  },
  Sales: [{...}]
}
```

I currently express the type like this:

```
type PaginatedResponse<TResponse extends object> = 
  TResponse & 
   Readonly<{
    PaginatedResponse: {
      TotalResults:  number;
      Offset: number;
      Limit: number;
      PageSize: number;
    };
    Error?: {
      Message: string;
      Code: string;
    };
  }>;
```

This has been working fine but I recently ran into a issue when I was trying to create a generic helper function to auto paginate an endpoint.

To keep track of all the results I need to do something like this:

```
const allResults = [...initialResults];
const nextResp = await apiCall();
allResults.push(...nextResp['Customers'])
```

But the problem is the key `'Customers'` can be any of the 50+ types the API may return. So I need a generic way to index into the response. I've tried a bunch of different things with no success so I'm looking to get some guidance on the best way to approach something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript alone will not be too helpful here. In `...nextResponse['Customers']` you are expecting TypeScript to fill in the correct key. But what the correct key is will only be known either ar runtime or by a manually supplied generic type.

But maybe this will help you anyway:

```js
// I added some generic types here which will help later
type PaginatedResponse<TResponse extends {[key in TKey]: any}, TKey extends keyof TResponse = keyof TResponse> = 
   Readonly<{
    PaginatedResponse: {
      TotalResults:  number,
      Offset: number,
      Limit: number,
      PageSize: number,
    };
    Error?: {
      Message: string;
      Code: string;
    };
  }> & TResponse
```

Define possible `Response` types:

```
type Response1 = PaginatedResponse<{Customers: any}>
type Response2 = PaginatedResponse<{Sales: any}>
type AllResponses = Response1 | Response2
```

Now let's define a function which gets a `PaginatedResponse` and pushes the `TResponse` in an array:

```
type GetResponseKey<T> =  T extends PaginatedResponse<infer TRes, infer TKey> ? TKey : never

const arr: any[] = []

function pushToResponseArray<
  T extends AllResponses, 
  K extends GetResponseKey<T>
>(response: T, key: K){
  arr.push(response[key])
}

const res: Response1 = {} as any

pushToResponseArray(res, "Customers") // We have to manually specify the key here
// but typescript will check if key is correct
```

This is not a perfect solution and I think you always have to either manually set the `key` or determine it with some JavaScript logic.

**To sum it up**:

Somewhere in your application you need some JavaScript logic to determine the type of the `PaginatedResponse`. Map the type to the corresponding key afterwards to access the `TResponse`.

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgcwJYDs7AgEwEoQM5gD2KeEAPACq4HGlQQAeGKmeUA3gNoDWEIUqKBQDSfALoAuKHBQgAvgBoho-o2asovEIQBmQ6kRLQAvJr679%20Q6QB8UUwCgoz3HEzEANiDLsnz2Iio6FgGtBBSvv7%20FITAcB7UAK4ewHhSUCiJALYARhAATgp%20UQDyOjqkwFKZuQVFUc4AMkhZSFUZ2XmFxf7wCBAAykgAXuEdtd1RcgDcPQCi%20fmE%20QD8ET3OALL4eIhjeMD5qAizDVAAwoSY%204fHp-4zfnJ2AGSWNEYODqCQUKFGAEZ7AFkGgMDgrGEfOdEgdCFkCmlpLJnt9wNB-qQAEzAvpBcGY8jsAbxfBSGTyGxo34AQQ8CUhRjYpkJQIAPn9Gdivj9oABxCDAQkqSh2UxCehMCAsNh4sEhLnkVA6ArvJTK1UiPh2FbKPhQaoQABuBS%20AGNaMBpItybJOGJgfavjpEigzcAkMQoGBYQALGKEmmLODeCiS9RsOkMj6kPBKYTh6UaAVCxUiig2GwACnyiqkFCUWikwgAlJFrfkAHQ%20vC%20nOKnjiEsOOTmy1QXNI1nA9hyaRsClfGv%20wiB4MgetxqAAIhhcIR%20Tw05LQA)